# out of memory exception for one record

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

we are using ASP.Net web application, migrated from vs 2008 to vs2013, updated the ajaxtoolkit 4.5, We are using ajax tab container and  usercontrols in tabs.
in one of the tabs, I am getting this unhandeled exception **OutOfMemory** there is **only one record in the datagrid**. can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this issue.
It was working fine few days ago and it is troubling us from last 4 days.  I really appreciate your help.

I gone through some posts on **google**, some of them suggests to change the properties to 64 bit or 32 bit, well setting for the application are set to **AllCPUs**
and for the out of memory exception it is now retrieving thousands of records to exceed 2gb or 4gb but only one row with 6-7 columns thats is what makes me post this.

The exception is as follows.

```
Exception of type System.Web.HttpUnhandledException was thrown.   
Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown.   System.SystemException System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.String.ToCharArray()  
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Write(String value)  
    at System.Web.UI.Page.RenderViewStateFields(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.BeginFormRender(HtmlTextWriter writer, String formUniqueID)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlFormWrapper.System.Web.UI.IHtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 





   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/site.Master" CodeBehind="OrderManagement.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserMaintainance.UserMaintainance.OrderManagement" %>   
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="ucl" TagName="ucSwapSerial" Src="~/UserControls/SwapSerial.ascx" %>   
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlContainer" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnPreRender="tabContainer_PreRender" CssClass="Tab" >
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TPnlSerialSwap" runat="server" HeaderText="Serial Swap" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="swapSerialTabClick">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSwapSerial" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <ucl:ucSwapSerial ID="ucSwapSerial" runat="server" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSwapSerialTrigger" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

//CodeBehind

```
protected void tabContainer_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TabsContainer_PreRender(sender, e);
    }

protected void TabsContainer_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DetermineTabsVisibility();

    }

    protected void DetermineTabsVisibility()
    {
        string activeTab;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Form[EVENT_TARGET] != null &&
           Request.Form[EVENT_TARGET] == (this.Master.FindControl(this.MenuButtonID)).UniqueID)
            //make it behave like a new page load   
            {
                this.ActiveTab = this.ActivePanels[0];
                //Yan: this line may raises a ArgumentOutOfRange exception in JavaScript, because ActiveTabIndex on client side may not match the server side
                //this.TabsContainer.ActiveTab = tp;
                this.TabsContainer.ActiveTabIndex = 0; 
                foreach (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp in this.TabsContainer.Tabs)

                         foreach (Control ctr in tp.Controls)
                            ctr.Visible = (tp.ID == this.ActiveTab);
                //Need to call the following method since there is no event handler handling this case senario
                SwitchToActiveTab();
                return;
            }
            activeTab = GetActiveTabToChange();
            //not new page load and not a changed tab;
            //event handler has already handles the control visibility
            if (activeTab == this.ActiveTab) 
                return;

            //not new page load but a changed tab
            foreach (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp in this.TabsContainer.Tabs)
                    foreach (Control ctr in tp.Controls)
                       ctr.Visible = (tp.ID == activeTab);


            this.ActiveTab = activeTab;
            //although eventhandler might already handles this (selectedindexchanged, etc.), we still need to switch the tab
            SwitchToActiveTab();
            return;
        }
        //      else, new page load indeed
       if (this.AccessibleTabs != null && this.TabsContainer != null)
        {
            foreach (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp in this.TabsContainer.Tabs)
            {
                tp.Visible = false;
                if (this.AccessibleTabs.Contains(tp.ID))
                {
                    tp.Visible = true;
                    foreach (Control ctr in tp.Controls)
                        ctr.Visible = true;

                }
            }
            SwitchToActiveTab();
        }
        else if (this.AccessibleTabs == null || this.AccessibleTabs.Count <= 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Helper.LOGIN_PAGE);
        }
    }

    //Usercontrol

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSerialList" runat="server" 
                    DataKeyNames="SerialNumberID" EnableViewState="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="False" onsorting="gvSerialList_Sorting"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="gvSerialList_PageIndexChanging" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSerialSelector" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumberID" HeaderText="SerialNumber ID" Visible="false" SortExpression="SerialNumberID"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ERPLineReference" HeaderText="Line #" Visible="false" SortExpression="ERPLineReference"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="Brightstar Part #" SortExpression="PartNumber"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PartDescription" HeaderText="Part Description" SortExpression="PartDescription"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Quantity"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumber" HeaderText="Serial" SortExpression="SerialNumber"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SIM" HeaderText="SIM" SortExpression="SIM"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialStatus" HeaderText="Serial Status" SortExpression="SerialStatus"/>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='QtyOnHand'></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShowQty" runat="server" Text="QtyOnHand"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuantity" runat="server" BackColor="YellowGreen" BorderStyle="Solid"><br /> <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDisplayHeader" runat="server" Text='<%# "Qty on Hand for Brightstar Part#: " + Eval("PartNumber")  + "<br />  <br> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp QtyOnHand &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Qty Available"%>'></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkShowQty_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                                    OkControlID="btnDlgClose"
                                    TargetControlID="lnkShowQty" 
                                    DynamicServicePath="~/WebServices/UIMaintenanceService.asmx"
                                    DynamicServiceMethod="GetPRSQuantityinHand"
                                    DynamicControlID="lblDisplay"
                                    PopupControlID="pnlQuantity"
                                    DynamicContextKey='<%#Eval("PartNumber") %>'
                                    BackgroundCssClass="modal"
                                    DropShadow="true">
                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                <br />
                                &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDlgClose" runat="server" Text="CLOSE" /> <br /> <br />                                                        </asp:Panel>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSerialSwap" runat="server" Text='SerialSwap'></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSerialSwap" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSerialSwap" DataTextField="SerialNumber"                                DataValueField="SerialNumberID" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlSerialStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                  {

                  }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid())
        {
                try
                {
                    lblJDEOrderID.Text = mpOrderAndSerialResponse.ResponseObject.ERPOrderID.ToString();
                    lblOrderID.Text = mpOrderAndSerialResponse.ResponseObject.OrderID.ToString();
                    gvSerialList.DataSource = mpOrderAndSerialResponse.ResponseObject.SerialList;
                    gvSerialList.DataBind();
                    SwapSerialMessages(string.Empty, MessageType.None);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: Yes my friend, Updated the post...

Comment: Something fishy with your viewstate. Try set `EnableViewState="False"` on the GridView (will cause issues probably). If it does not throw out of memory, post your SQL (or explain what the datasource contains). Edit: could be an issue with that `ucl:ucSwapSerial` or the nested UpdatePanel.